# Flask - generate secret key with urandom

Tags: python, flask

I am following the python/app engine tutorial here:
https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users
Specifically, it says "Flask recommends using urandom to generate a random key."
This is the example it gives:

```
python
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(24)
'\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'
```

This is probably very simple but the tutorial doesn't say what to do with this apart from copy/paste the final output and I am confused. What do I do with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set `app.secret_key`:

```
app.secret_key = '\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'
```

For that tutorial, the instruction is to set the secret key in your `config.py` file:

```
SECRET_KEY = '\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'
```